# How to set custom style in getInput function?

Tags: jinput

I thought there should be an easy way like:

```
echo $this->form->getInput('similar_text', array('style' => 'background: red;'));
```

But it seems to be harder than my except.

I need to generate an output like this:

```
<input type="text" name="jform_similar_text" style="background: red;" />
```

How should I do it using Joomla's Standard way?

Environment: Joomla 3.4

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Joomla! dosen't support `style` attribute on `text` field or sending it with `getInput` method.

I expect you know where `similar_text` field is defined in XML. If you don't then they are usually in `/components/COMPONENT_NAME/models/forms` for components. For modules, they are in general `.xml` file.

You should add `class` attribute to that field.

**XML**

```
<field 
    name="similar_text" 
    type="text"
    label="Similar text"
    class="inputbox red-bg" />
```

Then create .css file and load it on your extension. See [here](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Adding_JavaScript_and_CSS_to_the_page) how it's done.

**CSS**

```
input.red-bg{
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Create one xml file for example**

```
<field name="jform_similar_text"
            type="text"
            label="sample"
            description="sample"
            size="50"
            class="inputbox" />
```

**then write a default.php file in views**

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <?php echo $this->form->getLabel('jform_similar_text'); ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $this->form->getInput('jform_similar_text'); ?>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand. Possible for you to explain more clearly & with a step by step basis?